# bash how to concat multiple json files to one

Tags: text-processing, json, jq

I have thousands of json files that look like:

file1 (`key1:value_list1`)

```json
{"2mac:acg":["1-248","3-245","3-246","4-245","4-246","5-245","5-246","6-243","6-245","6-246","6-247","6-296","7-245","7-295","7-296","8-236","8-239","8-240","8-294","8-295","8-296","9-235","9-236","9-239","9-294","10-293","10-294","10-295","11-15","11-16","11-293","11-294","12-16","12-290","12-291","12-292","12-293","12-294","13-25","13-26","13-27","13-28","13-290","13-292","13-293","14-24","14-25","14-26","14-27","14-290","15-24","15-25","16-24","16-25","16-233","16-234","16-235","17-22","17-23","17-24","17-25","17-59","17-233","17-234","17-235","18-22","18-23","18-24","18-25","18-43","18-213","18-214","18-215","18-229","18-230","18-232","18-233","18-234","19-42","19-43"]}
```

file2 (`key2:value_list2`)

```json
{"4qld:aaa":["3-245","3-246","4-245","4-246","5-245","5-246","6-243","6-245","6-246","6-247","6-296","7-245","7-295","7-296","8-236","8-239","8-240","8-294","8-295","8-296","9-235","9-236","9-239","9-294","10-293","10-294","10-295","11-15","11-16","11-293","11-294","12-16","12-290","12-291","12-292","12-293","12-294","13-25","13-26","13-27","13-28","13-290","13-292","13-293","14-24","14-25","14-26","14-27","14-290","15-24","15-25","16-24","16-25","16-233","16-234","16-235","17-22","17-23","17-24","17-25","17-59","17-233","17-234","17-235","18-22","18-23","18-24","18-25","18-43","18-213","18-214","18-215","18-229","18-230","18-232","18-233","18-234","19-42","19-43","19-55"]}
```

file3 (`key3:value_list3`)

```json
{"6k8h:c":["1-248","2-134","3-245","3-246","4-245","4-246","5-245","5-246","6-243","6-245","6-246","6-247","6-296","7-245","7-295","7-296","8-236","8-239","8-240","8-294","8-295","8-296","9-235","9-236","9-239","9-294","10-293","10-294","10-295","11-15","11-16","11-293","11-294","12-16","12-290","12-291","12-292","12-293","12-294","13-25","13-26","13-27","13-28","13-290","13-292","13-293","14-24","14-25","14-26","14-27","14-290","15-24","15-25","16-24","16-25","16-233","16-234","16-235","17-22","17-23","17-24","17-25","17-59","17-233","17-234","17-235","18-22","18-23","18-24","18-25","18-43","18-213","18-214","18-215","18-229","18-230","18-232","18-233","18-234","19-42","19-43"]}
```

I want to merge these files into one, which should look like:

```json
{"2mac:acg":["1-248","3-245","3-246","4-245","4-246","5-245","5-246","6-243","6-245","6-246","6-247","6-296","7-245","7-295","7-296","8-236","8-239","8-240","8-294","8-295","8-296","9-235","9-236","9-239","9-294","10-293","10-294","10-295","11-15","11-16","11-293","11-294","12-16","12-290","12-291","12-292","12-293","12-294","13-25","13-26","13-27","13-28","13-290","13-292","13-293","14-24","14-25","14-26","14-27","14-290","15-24","15-25","16-24","16-25","16-233","16-234","16-235","17-22","17-23","17-24","17-25","17-59","17-233","17-234","17-235","18-22","18-23","18-24","18-25","18-43","18-213","18-214","18-215","18-229","18-230","18-232","18-233","18-234","19-42","19-43"], "4qld:aaa":["3-245","3-246","4-245","4-246","5-245","5-246","6-243","6-245","6-246","6-247","6-296","7-245","7-295","7-296","8-236","8-239","8-240","8-294","8-295","8-296","9-235","9-236","9-239","9-294","10-293","10-294","10-295","11-15","11-16","11-293","11-294","12-16","12-290","12-291","12-292","12-293","12-294","13-25","13-26","13-27","13-28","13-290","13-292","13-293","14-24","14-25","14-26","14-27","14-290","15-24","15-25","16-24","16-25","16-233","16-234","16-235","17-22","17-23","17-24","17-25","17-59","17-233","17-234","17-235","18-22","18-23","18-24","18-25","18-43","18-213","18-214","18-215","18-229","18-230","18-232","18-233","18-234","19-42","19-43","19-55"], "6k8h:c":["1-248","2-134","3-245","3-246","4-245","4-246","5-245","5-246","6-243","6-245","6-246","6-247","6-296","7-245","7-295","7-296","8-236","8-239","8-240","8-294","8-295","8-296","9-235","9-236","9-239","9-294","10-293","10-294","10-295","11-15","11-16","11-293","11-294","12-16","12-290","12-291","12-292","12-293","12-294","13-25","13-26","13-27","13-28","13-290","13-292","13-293","14-24","14-25","14-26","14-27","14-290","15-24","15-25","16-24","16-25","16-233","16-234","16-235","17-22","17-23","17-24","17-25","17-59","17-233","17-234","17-235","18-22","18-23","18-24","18-25","18-43","18-213","18-214","18-215","18-229","18-230","18-232","18-233","18-234","19-42","19-43"]}
```

the concat model should be `{key1:value_list_1, key2:value_list2, key3:value_list3}`

I used jq to concat them by `jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)' file1 file2 file3`. I surely got the result, but on one hand, it cost a long time if there are hundreds of files. on the other hand, the server (which does not belong to the group) doesn't have jq and I don't have the right to download it. So I was wondering if there are any other methods to deal with it. Thanks!

Comment: "_the server [...] doesn't have jq and I don't have the right to download it_". It's a managed server so there will be a process to have necessary software installed. For example a Change Board. Put your application through that for the `jq` to to be installed

Comment: If "the server" does not have `jq`, then install it (there is a static binary available from https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), or move the files to elsewhere and process them there.

Comment: the binary form worked. Thanks, @Kusalananda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usign `jq` you can do it with:

```
jq -s 'add' file1 file2 file3
```

If the above is not fast enough or JSON processors are not available to you, and if your JSON is really simple, you could concatenate the files, after replacing their last  `}` to `,` for all but the last file, and their first `{` to empty string, for all but the first one. Hopefully you see this is not safe, because JSON is not simple text.

Comment: FYI: JQ defines `add` as : `def add: reduce .[] as $x (null; . + $x);` which is very similar to the original code. So `add` will not improve performance but readability :-)

Comment: @A.H. I never claimed it would.

Comment: You are right. And I did not claim you did :-)
The Q mentioned performance and I asked myself if using a builtin vs a custom expression helps with that or not and I wanted to make that clear to others thinking about the same aspect.

Comment: @A.H. also, you are right. I replied like that (to deny any possible charges by the law!) because of the "FYI". Thank you for your comments.